# Multiple digital signatures against one app

Tags: oauth2, jwt

Is it possible to set up multiple valid Digital Signatures against one app? as stated in the title? When we get to cert expiry dates converting the changeover is such a pain it would be nice if I could add the new cert before the expiry date then once all systems have moved over to the new cert separately removing the old cert.

Comment: No. Talk to your SF account rep if this is important to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At time of writing, no.

One connected app can only store and utilize a single certificate for digital signatures.

I suppose one way to work around that is to create a second connected app, though that would place more burden on the client (who would need to manage 2 sets of app credentials, and inspect the first auth request to determine if a second request should be made using the other connected app).

For what it's worth, Salesforce currently doesn't enforce cert expiry when it comes to digital signatures for connected apps. It's obviously bad practice to use an expired cert, but it is possible.

Comment: Agree with this comment, but not sure if it is "dangerous" in terms of JWT to use an expired cert. Expiry date is more for CA's and rotation

Comment: Yeah this is for rotation that the client does they treat JWT the same as two way SSL in that all certs must be replaced every year. It would be just nice if when they gave me the new cert I could just plop it in ready for the switch over then when they have said they've done the swap over disable/remove the old.